# Trigonometry / reference angle

Tags: trigonometry

My question is how to find the reference angle for the following angle?

**Θ=7π/6**

[image: trigonometry reference angle question picture]

what i get was $\dfrac{7\pi}{6}-\dfrac{6\pi}{6}= -\dfrac{11\pi}{6}$
i'm still unsure im doing it correctly

Comment: $7\pi/6 -\pi=+\pi/6.$ Reference angle is the smallest angle to the $x$ axis from the terminal side, as you have correctly indicated for this case.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The reference angle always lies in the first quadrant (from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}\pi$), so it would be $\frac{1}{6}\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a reference angle is an ACUTE angle formed by the terminal side of the angle and the horizontal axis. From your figure the reference angle is $7\pi/6-\pi=\pi/6$.